# Memory transaction exception forwarding in DML - Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu

Tags: simics, dml-lang

A user has a register in a bank implementing a read method through the *io_memory* interface.
The memory operation is served by a memory link returning *Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu* on the first attempt.
At first glance, he doesn’t see a way to propagate the stall exception upwards.

**The main question:**

How could he forward the stall exception to the caller of the register operation so it can retry?

**More details:**

Here is a piece of the read method he wants to implement:

```
method read() {
    ex=$io_memory.operation(&mop,info);
    if(ex==SIM_PE_Stall_Cpu )
        **# What to do here to inform the reader about the stall?**
}
```

I have also attached the following file with pseudo-code to understand better what he wants to get in his DML: [stall-sample.dml](https://pastecode.io/s/9prrsho4)

Looking at the attached DML script, the customer has two devices.
Here are more details about what the customer wants:

**Device 1:**

- To implement a read method from which it is possible to check if *Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu* occurs on Device 2.

**Device 2:**

- To implement a before_read method, including a mechanism to enable Device 1 to see the stall when *Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu* is gotten on Device 2.
- To implement a read method where it’s possible to get *Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu* from a memory link.
- To forward the stall exception to the caller of the register operation so it can retry.

I checked the content of the pci-device source files, but there is nothing to be considered useful for the use case described by the user.

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this topic.

Thanks,

-JC

Comment: This sounds remarkably like homework or an exam question. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421). Also, your question doesn't do a good job of meeting the requirements for SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages.

Comment: This is a valid reasonable basic DML question and it gets into some of the deeper aspects of how DML integrates with Simics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure how the `Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu` mechanism works exactly; the recommended way is to use the new `transaction` interface instead of `io_memory`, and use the `SIM_transaction_wait` function to handle stalled transactions. This requires Simics 6 and DML 1.4.

That said, I'll try to answer the question of how a DML 1.2 device can signal `Sim_PE_Stall_Cpu` to the initiator: DML 1.2 is hardcoded to return either `Sim_PE_No_Exception` or `SIM_PE_IO_Not_Taken` from `io_memory.operation` (see `dml-builtins.dml:bank.io_memory.operation`); however, it is possible to attach a different exception to the memop itself by `SIM_set_mem_op_exception`. If you override `read_access` instead of `read` in the register, then you can retrieve the memop through a method arg and set the exception. I don't know if this solves your problem, though; perhaps the CPU looks only at the `io_memory.operation` return value, disregarding `SIM_get_mem_op_exception`. In this case, you may need to insert a proxy object between memory-space and bank that converts any set exception to a return value.

But, please keep in mind that whatever code you write for this will have to be rewritten in terms of `transaction_t` within a few years, so migrating to transaction_t now would likely save you time in the longer term.

Comment: Hi Erick.

That's very helpful information.
Thank you very much for your support on this topic. 
I think we can consider it as solved.